# Installing Windows 7 x64 on Asus M5A78-M LX V2, SATA Driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ahci

I'm trying to install a fresh Windows 7 64bit on a computer with a M5A78L-M LX V2 motherboard and two SATA disks. The setup process shows the error "No device drivers were found. Make sure...". I've already tried browsing for the correct driver in the installation CD that came with the motherboard, browsing to the exact folder of the AHCI Win7x64 driver, and I've tried a bunch of other folders too (RAID and 32bit). I've also tried downloading the updated drivers from the Asus website and unzipping them on a USB stick, then browsing to the exact folder, but the setup still shows the error.

I'm using a official Windows7 x64 Home Premium ISO downloaded from DigitalRiver, but I've also tried Ultimate. Changing the SATA mode (IDE/AHCI/RAID) in the BIOS doesn't solve the problem either.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT after @AcePL commented the answer below:

Disk1, SATA channel 5, is a old Maxtor, 80GB. Empty, can be erased at will.

Disk2, SATA channel 6, is a Seagate, 1TB. It contains a Windows 7 x64 OEM setup with programs and some data I'd rather keep. It works, I can boot off from this one and use the PC. I'm just trying to install a fresh Windows 7 x64 on the other disk in order to experiment on it.

The two disks are on channels 5 and 6 instead of 1 and 2 because 1 is taken by the optical unit. Channels 3 and 4 are hard to reach with the fingers to plug the cables in (but feasible if you believe that could change anything). in the BIOS SATA channels 1-4 can be configured IDE/AHCI/RAID in a single entry for all four, and the same goes for 5-6, but the two options (mode for 1-4 and mode for 5-6) are somewhat independent of each other.

EDIT 2:

I've moved the HDDs to ports 1&2 and optical drive to 5. The [AUTO] option is not available for any SATA ports, not for 1-4 nor for 5&6. Tried again IDE mode, AHCI mode, original drivers that came with the mainboard, downloaded ones (from Asus), even the upstream drivers from AMD (Omega 14.12). Nothing worked. I'm going to give up and buy a new PC. Sadly, I know there IS a way to install Windows 7 on this crap, because someone already installed it once, but I'm not skilled enough to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is still having this issue, the drivers you need are for USB3. The other option is to install Windows from a CD or moving your bootable flash drive to a usb 2.0 port.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command set after you boot to recovery mode from DVD:

1. diskpart
2. list disk
3. select disk [insert number here]
4. clean

Comment: CLEAN? Is that safe? Will that wipe my disk?

Comment: I've installed a new HD in place of the second HD and tried those commands selecting that disk. Nothing changed. diskpart lists both disks, but the setup does not proceed and keeps asking for a driver.

Comment: Yes, that will wipe the disk of all data.

More data on the disks, please. Capacity, interface, what's on them now?

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: according to the manual if you want to connect HDD on ports 5 and 6 they have to be set to [AUTO]. It states that this option is available only for 5&6.
if that doesn't work you need to move HDDs to ports 1-4. There is no need to work them in pairs - there is no master/slave designation in AHCI/RAID setting. Also, your OS drive should be connected to SATA0 (however it's not required). After that which device to which port is not critical. However, on your system, I gather opticals should be on 5 &/or 6.

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: Ok. I'm looking through http://www.manualowl.com/m/Asus/M5A78L-M-LX-V2/Manual/264317 and several things need to be confirmed: 1. Is Onchip SATA enabled? I'm pretty sure it is, but check. SOmetimes it's good to disable, reboot then enable back and reboot again... 2. Disabled Quickboot? 3. Is there a security password on for either user or supervisor?

Comment: Last thing to check would be clearing CMOS. Set BIOS to default, disconnect power cable, remove battery from motherboard and then repeatedly press Power button (or press and hold for 30 sec). Last ditch proposition: update BIOS. This also sometimes clears some internal settings... Because from all descriptions the system recognizes HDDs but prevents OS installer from accessing them. Which means there's some kind of lock. On related note: you're sure drives are not encrypted?

Comment: Updated the BIOS, no dice. No drive encryption. Ended up installing Windows 8.1, that worked like a charm and it didn't even ask for the Asus drivers.

Comment: Hmpf.... Thank you for that bit of info. But it begs the question: what Windows was that you tried to install? OEM? BOX? Was it a commercial version at all or maybe eval copy?

Comment: The Windows that finally worked is a Windows 8.1 x64 Professional from MSDN. The one that did not work was a Windows 7 x64 Home Premium downloaded from DigitalRiver. All the steps before "Last ditch proposition: update BIOS" have been tried and failed, though I didn't mention that in my previous comment.